# Best option for Unit Test using PHP4

Tags: php, unit-testing

I'm working on a project that is stuck in php4 and I'm intending to run some UnitTests for some new areas that I'm working on it.

**What is the best framework to do UnitTest on PHP4?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would this older version of PHPUnit be enough for what you need? http://pear.php.net/package/PHPUnit/redirected

Comment: @Sefam, we are pretty open I was wondering to collect some tips&tricks before dig on some framework. I'll try it... tks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

1)[Simpletest](http://www.simpletest.org/)

It is a PHP unit test and web test framework.It has support for SSL, forms, frames, proxies and basic authentication. The idea is that common but fiddly PHP tasks, such as logging into a site, can be tested easily.

2)[PHPUnit Automated Unit Testing Framework](http://www.slideshare.net/csixty4/phpunit-automated-unit-testing-framework)

It provides a simple framework for creating a test suite to automate testing of functions and classes. PHPUnit stands alone as a good tool for testing classes or a set of functions and will ease your development cycle and help you to avoid endless debug sessions.